# Solving Project Euler #12 with Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am trying to solve Problem #12 of Project Euler with Matlab and this is what I came up with to find the number of divisors of a given number:

```
function [Divisors] = ND(n)
p = primes(n); %returns a row vector containing all the prime numbers less than or equal to n
i = 1;
count = 0;
Divisors = 1;

  while n ~= 1
      while rem(n, p(i)) == 0 %rem(a, b) returns the remainder after division of a by b
          count = count + 1;
          n = n / p(i);
      end
      Divisors = Divisors * (count + 1);
      i = i + 1;
      count = 0;
  end

end
```

After this, I created a function to evaluate the number of divisors of the product `n * (n + 1) / 2` and when this product achieves a specific limit:

```
function [solution] = Solution(limit)
n = 1;
product = 0;

  while(product < limit)
     if rem(n, 2) == 0
         product = ND(n / 2) * ND(n + 1);
     else
         product = ND(n) * ND((n + 1) / 2);
     end
     n = n + 1;
  end

  solution = n * (n + 1) / 2;

end
```

I already know the answer and it's not what comes back from the function `Solution`. Could someone help me find what's wrong with the coding.

When I run `Solution(500)` (500 is the limit specified in the problem), I get `76588876`, but the correct answer should be:

> `76576500`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is quite simple while it also bothering me for a while: The iteration in you `while` loop is misplaced, which would cause the solution a little bigger than the true answer.

```
function [solution] = Solution(limit)
n = 1;
product = 0;

  while(product < limit)
     n = n + 1;     %%%But Here
     if rem(n, 2) == 0
         product = ND(n / 2) * ND(n + 1);
     else
         product = ND(n) * ND((n + 1) / 2);
     end
     %n = n + 1;    %%%Not Here
  end

  solution = n * (n + 1) / 2;

end
```

The output of Matlab 2015b:

```
>> Solution(500)

ans =

    76576500
```